# Find duplicates, add to variable and remove

Tags: python, django, counter

I have a script that writes sales values to separate lines in a file and the ultimate goal is to save the data into a database. The problem I'm running into is that there are duplicate entries for the same sales person, date, product, price and quantity.

My code is written like this to the file:

```
John 07-15-2016 Tool Belt $100 2
Sara 07-15-2016 Hammer $100 3
John 07-15-2016 Tool Belt $100 2
John 07-15-2016 Tool Belt $100 2
Sara 07-15-2016 Hammer $100 3
```

How do I remove the duplicates and add them together? i.e. the output to be:

```
John 07-15-2016 Tool Belt $100 6
Sara 07-15-2016 Hammer $100 6
```

I've used counter but it doesn't catch multiple instances, nor can I find a way to add the two together.

Any help would be appreciated.

Script:

```
for line in s:
        var = re.compile(r'(\$)',re.M)
        line = re.sub(var, "", line)
        var = re.compile(r'(\,)',re.M)
        line = re.sub(var, "", line)
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        line = line.split("|")
        if line[0] != '':
            salesperson = str(salesperson)
            date = dt.now()
            t = line[0].split()
            print t
            t = str(t[0])
            try:
                s = dt.strptime(t, "%H:%M:%S")
            except:
                s = dt.strptime(t, "%H:%M")
            s = s.time()
            date = dt.combine(date, s)
            date = str(date)
            price = line[1]
            quantity = line[2]
        fn.write("%s %s %s %s \n" % (salesperson, date, price, quantity))
    fn.close()
```

Comment: How are you writing the file? show the relevant part of your script

Comment: @Gocht I edited it to show the script

Comment: You could create a dictionary to keep track of values as you read the file, and only write once you are finished processing your data. Writing along the way doesn't allow you to back-track effectively.

Comment: @Hobbes I don't mind having to open the file again if that's what it would take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sample.csv

```
John 07-15-2016 Tool Belt $100 2
Sara 07-15-2016 Hammer $100 3
John 07-15-2016 Tool Belt $100 2
John 07-15-2016 Tool Belt $100 2
Sara 07-15-2016 Hammer $100 3
```

test.py

```
with open("sample.csv") as inputs:
    mydict = dict()
    for line in inputs:
        elements = line.strip().split()
        key = " ".join(elements[0: len(elements) - 1]) 
        mydict[key] = mydict.get(key, 0) + int(elements[-1])

    # iterate the dictionary and print out result
    for key, value in mydict.iteritems():
        print "{0} {1}".format(key, value)
```

I use a dictionary, split each line and use first `len(elements) - 1` elements as a key, and then  increase the last elements when iterate all lines.

`mydict.get(key, 0)` returns value if key exist in the dictionary, otherwise return value 0

result:
python2.7 test.py

```
Sara 07-15-2016 Hammer $100 6
John 07-15-2016 Tool Belt $100 6
```

Therefore in your case you need:

```
elements = line.strip().split()
key = " ".join(elements[0: len(elements) - 1]) 
mydict[key] = mydict.get(key, 0) + int(elements[-1])
```

Comment: @Dorian glad it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files is called records.txt

To Split the file into a separate file for each salesperson:

`awk '{print > $1}' records.txt`

Then to count specific items per salesperson:

`cat Sara | grep 'Hammer' | awk '{print $NF,sum}' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`

Comment: @Dorian, you could grep the salesperson first then get single counts for each sales person. Just a thought to help break the problem into a smaller problem. :)